# How to use extended glyphicons in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn, glyphicons

I downloaded the glyphicons from http://glyphicons.com/ as a folder of png-files. How can I use them in bootstrap? Note that I use the CDN of bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Now I use bootstrap 4 with font-awesome.

Answer (score -1):

create a separate `css` file for each icon set (full, filetypes & social) and copied the way bootstrap initializes them  i.e.

```
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-power"></span>
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-heart-empty"></span>
```

and also try, `glyphicons glyphicon-user` instead of `glyphicons glyphicons-user`

List of changes for Bootstrap 3 http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? How should the css-file look like?

Comment: Bootstrap considers icons as a font and I downloaded png-files, so simply copy-paste would not work....